# Adding label to contour

Tags: matplotlib

This code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.contourf(np.random.random((10,10)), label='my_label')
plt.legend()
```

produces this warning:

> warnings.warn("No labeled objects found.")

Does anyone know how to label contour?
I just want to annotate automatically generated contours inside plot window the easiest possible way.

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.contourf do the examples here do what you want?  I am confused by your use of legend and saying you want to annotate the curves.

Comment: These are filled contours. On your linked example that's classical legend on contour lines. I don't want to do that. I want to name the plot, but not with `title()` which would appear outside the plot windows, but inside. I thought to try with label, like in regular plot, but it doesn't work.

Comment: OK, I think I can make it with `annotate()` function and then I'll post that as answer.

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/mpl_examples/pylab_examples/contourf_demo_01.png ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used [`annotate()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=annotate#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate) function to label my filled contour:

[image: screenshot]

In above code, instead `plt.legend()` I used:

`plt.annotate('my_label', (8, 1), backgroundcolor='w')`

So only additional consideration compared to `label` parameter, is that user needs to know the coordinates where the text will be positioned. Or so I think.

Update: As suggested in the comments, user can choose `axes fraction` type for `xycoords` parameter and use relative reference in range [0,1] to set mandatory `xy` point parameter:

`plt.annotate('my_label', (.9, .1), xycoords='axes fraction', backgroundcolor='w')`

Comment: Ah, did not understand your question at all;) You can use axes units with annotate, http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate see the doc on the kwarg `xycoords` and `textcoords`

Comment: Yep, that's why I wrote that user needs to know plot coordinates (array shape), while label can be positioned without such considerations (ie. 'upper left', 'center', 'best', etc)

Comment: You are using data coordinates.  Axes coordinates go from `[0, 0]` (lower left) to `[1, 1]` (upper right) and are fraction of axes height and width.

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_guide.html,   http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks @tcaswell, I updated my answer to include your findings.