# Is it possible to add a string as a legend item

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, legend, legend-properties

I am producing some plots in matplotlib and would like to add explanatory text for some of the data. I want to have a string inside my legend as a separate legend item above the '0-10' item. Does anyone know if there is a possible way to do this?

[image]

This is the code for my legend:
`ax.legend(['0-10','10-100','100-500','500+'],loc='best')`

Comment: If there isn't a proper way of doing this the only other option I can think of is to trick the graph into producing it by plotting some empty values

Comment: Try `annotate()` function. I just asked similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823703/adding-label-to-contour

Comment: Why not simply set the legends `title`? I.e. `ax.legend(['0-10','10-100','100-500','500+'], loc='best', title='Explanatory text')`.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Sure. `ax.legend()` has a two argument form that accepts a list of objects (handles) and a list of strings (labels). Use a dummy object (aka a ["proxy artist"](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#using-proxy-artist)) for your extra string.  I picked a `matplotlib.patches.Rectangle` with no fill and 0 linewdith below, but you could use any supported artist.

For example, let's say you have 4 bar objects (since you didn't post the code used to generate the graph, I can't reproduce it exactly).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
bar_0_10 = ax.bar(np.arange(0,10), np.arange(1,11), color="k")
bar_10_100 = ax.bar(np.arange(0,10), np.arange(30,40), bottom=np.arange(1,11), color="g")
# create blank rectangle
extra = Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc="w", fill=False, edgecolor='none', linewidth=0)
ax.legend([extra, bar_0_10, bar_10_100], ("My explanatory text", "0-10", "10-100"))
plt.show()
```

[image: example output]

Comment: Thanks, this works. I'd also like to do this with a different plot that has a line plotted on top of the bars, but I get the following error c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\legend.py:628: UserWarning: Legend does not support [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x0A7027B0>]
Use proxy artist instead.

Comment: it's actually a really common thing.  I bet you've done something like: `line = ax.plot(x, y)`. The issue is that `plot` returns a *list* of lines, so you need to get at the actual artist.  You can either do `line = ax.plot(x, y)[0]` or do `line, = ax.plot(x, y)` which takes advantage of parameter unpacking.

Comment: It is better to set the rectangle transparent to fit with any background: `Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, alpha=0)`

Answer (score 117):

Alternative solution, kind of dirty but pretty quick.

```
import pylab as plt

X = range(50)
Y = range(50)
plt.plot(X, Y, label="Very straight line")

# Create empty plot with blank marker containing the extra label
plt.plot([], [], ' ', label="Extra label on the legend")

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It works, but it is a hack.

Comment: Is there any way of adding a string to the white space created from using this method?

Answer (score 18):

I found another way to do that
just try:

```py
plt.legend(title='abc xyz')
```

I used this in my work!
[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer; this does exactly what the OP wanted and is not hacky at all.

Answer (score 0):

If using the object oriented approach you can do as [S.B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71336853/13419456) suggested:

```py
fig.legend(title="...")

# or

ax.legend(title="...")
```

There is also a setter:

```py
legend = ax.legend()  # place legend object 
legend.set_title(f"...")  # set the additional title
```

Comment: When your title is longer than the labels and you want to (left-)adjust all contents, you can use `legend._legend_box.align = "left"`.