# How do I target a list element of a MatPlotLib object that "returns a list"?

Tags: oop, python-2.7, matplotlib

Help me understand a little more about working with the matplot library of objects (which may really be a *programming with Python* question). This is a good example of the question. A comment says `plot()` command returning a list of objects:

> "... plot returns a list of lines, so you need to get at
>   the actual artist. You can either do line = ax.plot(x, y)[0] or do
>   line, = ax.plot(x, y) which takes advantage of parameter unpacking." --
>   [Is it possible to add a string as a legend item in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826711/is-it-possible-to-add-a-string-as-a-legend-item-in-matplotlib)

But its not really a *list* of objects being returned, but wrapped up by another class,

```
(Pdb) p ax1
<matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot object at 0x7fe4ba05e550>
```

I can't target the elements of the list in the normal way from the ax object:

```
(Pdb) ax1[0]
*** TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object does not support indexing
```

What do I need to understand about objects in Python (jumping in between the classes--I've never seen `fun(a,b)[0]` before) to take advantage of what the comment is saying about the plot object returning a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're just misreading that comment. If you have an `AxesSubplot` called `ax1`, and you run:

```
l = ax1.plot(x,y)
```

The `type` of `l` will be `list` (or some `list`-like object). The [documentation for `plot`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot) states this, too:

> **plot(*args, **kwargs)**
>
> Plot lines and/or markers to the Axes. args is a variable length argument, allowing for multiple x, y pairs with an optional format string.
>
> ...
>
> Return value is a list of lines that were added.

So this:

```
line = ax.plot(x, y)[0]
```

Is just a shortcut for this:

```
lines = ax.plot(x, y)
line = lines[0]
```

It's not saying that the `AxesSubplot` object itself is a list, it's just saying that one of the instance methods of that object returns a list when you call it.

Comment: It was there but I just didn't see it, **[** <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7fe4b9e3c3d0> **]**.
I've just never seen that shortcut before and it confused me.