# how t add p value as legend into axes in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, p-value

I have the following code :

```
def plot_diff_dist(ax, simulations, real_difference, bins=20):
    p=pvalue(simulations, real_difference)
    ax.hist(simulations, bins=bins )
    ax.axvline(real_difference, color='r', linewidth=5)
```

later plot_diff_dist will be called with other functions that plots histogram on different axes, i need to add p as a legend to every histogram it produces. so i need to change this function to attach p as a legend to every histogram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try this solution from SO [`post.`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826711/is-it-possible-to-add-a-string-as-a-legend-item-in-matplotlib)

```
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.normal(2500,size=1000)})

ax = df.plot.hist()
ax.axvline(2501,color='r', linewidth=2)
extra = Rectangle((0, 0), 100, 100, fc="w", fill=False, edgecolor='none', linewidth=0)
ax.legend([extra],('p = 1.2',"x")).2',"x"))
```

Edit: Show P as a variable:

```
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.normal(2500,size=1000)})
ax = df.plot.hist()
p=1.2
ax.axvline(2501,color='r', linewidth=2)
extra = Rectangle((0, 0), 100, 100, fc="w", fill=False, edgecolor='none', linewidth=0)
ax.legend([extra],('p = {}'.format(p),"x"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, in my problem p is a variable, how can i change your code to accept variable as p? it is not a string

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have some code to produce a histogram like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)

x = np.random.poisson(3, size=100)
p = 5.
plt.hist(x, bins=range(10))
l = plt.axvline(p, color="crimson")
```

#### legend

You can use a [`legend`](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html) and provide your axvline as legend handler, as well as the formatted value as legend text.

```
plt.legend([l], ["p={}".format(p)], loc=1)
```

[image]

#### text

You can use [`text`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text) to place a text in the figure. By default, the coordinates are data coordinates, but you can specify a transform to switch e.g. to axes coordinates.

```
plt.text(.96,.94,"p={}".format(p), bbox={'facecolor':'w','pad':5},
         ha="right", va="top", transform=plt.gca().transAxes )
```

[image]

#### annotate

You can use [`annotate`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate) to produce a text somewhere in the figure. The advantage compared to `text` is that you may (a) use an additional arrow to point to an object, and (b) that you may specify the coordinate system in terms of a simple string, instead of a transform.

```
plt.annotate("p={}".format(p), xy=(p, 15), xytext=(.96,.94), 
            xycoords="data", textcoords="axes fraction",
            bbox={'facecolor':'w','pad':5}, ha="right", va="top",
            arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05, width=1))
```

[image]

#### AnchoredText

You can use an [`AnchoredText`](https://matplotlib.org/api/offsetbox_api.html#matplotlib.offsetbox.AnchoredText) from offsetbox:

```
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnchoredText
a = AnchoredText("d={}".format(d), loc=1, pad=0.4, borderpad=0.5)
plt.gca().add_artist(a)
```